# Lambda function - How to split python code across multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

**Problem**

I'm trying to split my python code for a lambda function across multiple files however any attempt to import the other relative modules throws an error for the top level module.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'download_ga_data'"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? This feels like it should be super basic.

**File structure layout (shown from root)**

```
- download_ga_data.py
   - [analytics]
        - google.py (contains a single class)
        - __init__.py
   - [helpers]
        - main.py (contains a single class)
        - __init__.py
   - {other libraries from site-packages}
```

**Contents of download_ga_data.py**

```
# import unicodecsv as csv
import os

# import path
from . import definitions
from analytics.google import GoogleAnalytics
from helpers.main import GoogleCloudStorageBucket

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("test")
```

This as it stands will throw the error. If I comment out the three imports after os, then it will function correctly.

How should I correctly import these two modules, I feel like I'm missing something super basic.

**Environment notes**

This is all built on a the following [lambda mimicking docker](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) and uploaded straight into S3. All the files are 777 to bypass any permissions errors.

Comment: should it be `from helpers.main import GoogleCloudStorageBucket` ?

Comment: @maxymoo oop that's a mis-type in the original question. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finally solved this. The main tip I received to help with this was to wrap my load functions in a try except block:

```
try:
    import definitions
    from analytics.google import GoogleAnalytics
    from cloud_helpers.main import GoogleCloudStorageBucket
except Exception as e:
    error = str(e)
    stacktrace = json.dumps(traceback.format_exc())
    message = "Exception: " + error + "  Stacktrace: " + stacktrace
    err = {"message": message}
    return respond(err)

def respond(err, res=None):
    return {
        "statusCode": "400" if err else "200",
        "body": err["message"] if err else json.dumps(res),
        "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    }
```

This then revealed the following error (which I irritatingly only have a screenshot of):

[image]

Which was then solved by switching to `import definitions`